# How to move two Views synchronously in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, surfaceview

My question is quite simple:

I have an `ImageView` (set as background) and an `ImageButton` (sitting on the ImageView) in a `layout` or `ViewGoup`. Now I scroll or drag the layout hoping that these two views move together, unfortunately the relative position of these two views is not fixed when moving. Only after the drag is finished, the relative position of them is the same as the beginning.

Any idea to resolve the issue? Thanks.

---

Update:

I am doing a project like Google maps.

I draw map tiles into a `SurfaceView` and when drag the map, the `SurfaceView` will update the tiles. Now I have some poi icons (ImageButton) which are click-able, the poi icons are fixed in the map. (SurfaceView and ImageButtons are put into the same layout or a ViewGroup.) When I drag the map, I update the `SurfaceView` and update the positions of the poi icons too. However, it is impossible for these two procedures to occur in the same time, i.e. in the dragging process, the positions of the poi icons are changing in the map, only after finish the drag, the poi icons come to their correct positions in the map. I just want a good looking of the poi icons (not shaking in the map) when dragging the map.
How does `Google maps` do it? (There are so many elements on the map and drag the map, they are moving together just like embedded in the map, in the meantime, they are click-able.)

Comment: Can you share some code? layout xmls at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `ImageButton`s you can draw your "poi icons" over `SurfaceView` just like you did with the map tiles and then set an `OnClickListener` to the `SurfaceView` to catch click events.

Comment: Well, that's some kind of the solution I am currently using. I override onTouchEvent for my customized SurfaceView and use onSingleTapConfirmed from a GestureDetector (extends SimpleOnGestureListener) to capture the clicked point position to see whether it triggers a poi clicking function. When I drag the map, I need update the trigger area of all of the poi icons too. I am just thinking that maybe there is another decent way to handle my situation, such as making the poi icons as ImageButtons.

Comment: Since SurfaceView does its own rendering out of the main(UI)-thread, using it with other views cause choppy UI's. So your best bet is drawing them on the SurfaceView. Updating all poi icons trigger area is a bad idea. Isn't that these icons bound to coordinates? Why don't you just calculate coordinate that user clicked and check if there is a poi icon with some error margin?

Comment: The other views can be updated in a handler thread by calling postInvalidate() method. So using other views with SurfaceView will not be a big problem. Indeed updating all poi icons trigger area is not a good idea. I will follow your suggestion to calculate the coordinate of the clicked point. It seems that this is the final solution. Thanks.

Comment: The thing is postInvalidate() doesn't update the view immediately so when dragging icons won't move as smooth as you may think, that is why  I called it choppy. Please accept this answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put the imageview and the imagebutton in different places and expect that when you drag the imageview the imagebutton will also be dragged. For this to work put both the imageview and imagebutton inside a wrapper layout (relative layout) and make this relative layout draggable.

Comment: I do put them together in a wrapper layout. And in the process of dragging this layout, the relative position of the two views is not fixed.